# Django REST Framework get list view by FK

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

```
class Project(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(USER)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=(('NEW', 'NEW'), ('CLOSE', 'CLOSE'), ('CANCEL', 'CANCEL')))

class Investment(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=(('BOOKED', 'BOOKED'), ('FAIL', 'FAIL'), ('CANCEL', 'CANCEL')))

class ProjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    investment = InvestmentSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ('id', 'status', 'investment')

class ProjectView(mixins.ListModelMixin, mixins.RetrieveModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    serializer_class = ProjectSerializer
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Project.objects.filter(user=self.request.user, status__in= ['CLOSE', 'CANCEL'], investment__status__in=["FAIL", "CANCEL"]))
```

I want a project view, only investment's status is 'FAIL' or 'CANCEL', but above code all investment in the result not only status is 'FAIL' or 'CANCEL', how to do this?

Comment: Simple I can suggest of having `related_name='investment',` at     `project = models.ForeignKey(Project,related_name='investment')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use the filter inside serializer method field of the `ProjectSerializer` for example:

```
class ProjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    investment = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_investment(self, obj):
         qs = obj.investment.filter(status__in=["FAIL", "CANCEL"])
         serializer = InvestmentSerializer(qs, many=True)
         return serializer.data
```

more details [serializermethodfield](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield)